# when do maven "reports" get run?

Tags: java, maven

I have used Maven 3 for several years without having to mess with the "reports" section.   However, now I need to configure something to run a report.   Our projects take a long time to build so I would like to **only** run the report, if possible (as opposed to building the whole project over and over again.)

What causes the "reports" section of a POM.XML to get activated?   I would think this would be in the documentation, but apparently it's so obvious to everyone that it was never written down.   I've tried various build options, goals, combinations, etc and can't seem to get these reports to run.

Can someone tell me the build options to execute only the "reports" section of the POM?

Comment: Are you talking about this plugin? http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-project-info-reports-plugin/

Comment: I'm actually talking about the whole `<reporting>` section of the pom, which you can see in this example for the plugin you mentioned:   http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-project-info-reports-plugin/examples/selective-project-info-reports.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running `mvn site` should create those reports without an explicit build.
That surely depends on what you mean by "reports", but if it is the `<reporting>` section with the `maven-project-info-reports-plugin` , the command should do it's job.

Comment: I don't think we've ever used `mvn site` for anything, so this is new territory for me.  Thank you for the answer, it helped immensely.